# How to run gradle with caches files

Tags: gradle, caching

I'm using old dependencies which can't be downloaded any more. But I have dependance package in ./gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1.
But on grade build, gradle try to downloaded it in throws exception Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1

How to run gradle with caches files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a dependency on a file in your file system. Eg

```
dependencies {
    implementation files("/path/to/my/favourite/dependency.jar")
}
```

Probably best to also move it out of your cache folder and put it somewhere safer if it can't be easily re-obtained.